# Mouseleave and Mouseenter on Material Dialog box

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

The problem I am having is that the mouseleave event gets triggered anytime I move the cursor within the element. The dialog box opens and closes if they are still inside the element. Is there a way to prevent it? Please see stackblitz for example.

```
export class DialogElementsExample {
    
      public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogElementsExampleDialog>
      constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}
    
      openDialog() {
       this.dialogRef =  this.dialog.open(DialogElementsExampleDialog);
      }
    
      closeDialog(){
      console.log("close");
      this.dialogRef.close();
    }
    }


    <div>
      <button mat-button (mouseleave)="closeDialog()" (mouseenter)="openDialog()">Launch dialog</button>
    </div>
    
    
    <p style="background-color:red" (mouseleave)="closeDialog()" (mouseenter)="openDialog()">
      TEST 123 123 123 123 123
    <P>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3pqnyp?embed=1&file=src/app/dialog-elements-example.ts

Comment: From what I'm seeing, your mouse events are competing with each other. When the dialog opens, your mouse 'leaves' the button (since it is now over the dialog background), which triggers a close. You should leave the closing of the modal to things inside the modal itself rather than the button you're using to launch it.

Comment: yeah, @redouglas is right you should delegate closing action to the dialog itself